# Unable to verify certificate error when using Carrierwave and Fog to connect to AWS for image storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, amazon-web-services

I've been beating my head against my screen for several days now trying to get this to work.  Any advice would be appreciated. I get the following message when trying to upload images to Amazon Web Services using the Carrierwave and Fog-AWS gems. Changing the storage to :file works.

```
Unable to verify certificate, please set `Excon.defaults[:ssl_ca_path] = path_to_certs`, `ENV['SSL_CERT_DIR'] = path_to_certs`, `Excon.defaults[:ssl_ca_file] = path_to_file`, `ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = path_to_file`, `Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_callback] = callback` (see OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext#verify_callback), or `Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_peer] = false` (less secure).
```

Gem file (I pulled the master carrierwave as suggested in another topic):

```
gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
gem "fog-aws"
```

Initializer (carrierwave.rb) (Including region doesn't solve):

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        # required
  config.fog_credentials = {
    :provider               => 'SECRET',                        # required
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'SECRET',                        # required
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'SECRET',
  }
  config.fog_directory  = 'directoryname'                          # required
end
```

Uploader:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :fog

end
```

I'm on Windows 7 and my current SSL certs:

```
    $ ruby -ropenssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'
OpenSSL 1.0.0o 15 Oct 2014
```

Comment: Have you tried setting SSL_CERT_FILE environment variable  ? (If you installed via Ruby installer I think it provides a certificate bundle in c:\rubyinstaller). There are also many questions on this topic here - did you try any of those proposed solutions ?